# Show that $P(B\mid A^C)+P(B^C\mid A^C)=1$

Tags: probability, independence

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are any two events and $P(A)>0$, show that $$P(B\mid A^C)+P(B^C\mid A^C)=1$$

---

How do i go about answering this properly?

Comment: You could use formulas? You have a formula for conditional probability, right?

Comment: Shouldn't we rather have $P(A)<1$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen P(A)>0 is what my textbook is saying.

Comment: This question was posted several times! But anyway, this is not hard to show!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the definition for conditional probability of two events 
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
And see where it takes you. Try drawing a Venn diagram.